# Is it possible to write analog of shapeless Generic.from without macros

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-macros

I'm writing my own minimalistic `HList`/`Generic` implementations to derive encoders for several my own case classes.

I managed to write `ToTuple` evidence, but all my case classes have over 22 members, so I cannot use `tupled` function. Also I'd like to avoid using macros if possible.

Is it possible to convert HList to case class without macros?

Beside of limitations my use case also have few reliefs (not sure if they can help):

- There's no sealed traits, only case classes
- All case classes I need to decode are in my library, so I can add minimal boilerplate to their definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming case class into hlist is maybe possible using `.productIterator`.
But transforming hlist into case class is possible either with macros (or shapeless where macros are used under the hood) or writing methods like

```
case class MyClass(i: Int, s: String, b: Boolean)

object MyClass {
  def from(x: Int :: String :: Boolean :: HNil): MyClass = x match {
    case i :: s :: b :: HNil => MyClass(i, s, b)
  }
}
```

for every case class. The thing is you can't write

```
def from[T](x: ...): T = new T(...) //pseudocode
```

without macros (or reflection).

Comment: Yep, that pretty much what I thought and answers my question. Thanks.